# Announces with different formatting dependently on a number

Tags: loop, content

I am modifying the theme TwentyEleven.

In index.php there is the loop which accesses content.php template:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

  <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The trouble is that I need different formatting (different classes) for odd and even posts. How to do this?

My only idea is to remove content.php and insert the code directly to index.php with variable $i counting the position in the loop (by ++$i). But that's bad.

Comment: This isn't really a WordPress question. You can use the nth-child CSS selector, or toggle a class outpout variable in PHP.

Comment: @anu But it can be done nicely with wp core functions.

Answer (score 1):

Open up `content.php` and replace this:

```
<?php post_class(); ?>
```

...with this:

```
<?php post_class( ++$GLOBALS['wp_query']->wpse60971_current_post % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd' ); ?>
```